# Can a batsman complete a run outside the 2 metre wide cricket pitch?

Tags: rules, cricket

In hitting a potential winning run in a tied cricket match my brother's bat slipped out of his hand and over the square leg umpire's head. He did not realise that a bat is not needed to complete a run, so he ran and collected it then headed for the bowler's crease, which allowed time for him to be run out.

If he had run parallel to the pitch and reached a point past an imaginary extension of the popping crease at the bowler's end, would the run of counted, and/or would he have been out?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Quoting from [Law 7 The Creases](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/the-creases):

> The popping crease [...] shall be considered to be unlimited in length.

so you can complete the run anywhere on the playing surface.